# Simple RS232 to 8 bit Parallel circuit

Tags: rs232, parallel, converter

I want to make a simple rs232 to parallel (8 bit) converter.

I would like the input to 1 wire and the output can just be 8 bit with no strobes etc. and run at high speeds (ideally up to 1Mbps, put ~100kbps would be ok)

Ideally, what would be simplest circuit to achieve this? I tried to work it out but it ended up being quite complex, multiple cloks/monostables, shift register, decade counter.. So, I thought I'd post here as I thought there may be a trick to simplify it or a specific chip. Ideally CMOS.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter Bennett has the right idea, I think.

If you Google on "6402 UART" you can find the part you need - Jameco, for instance, sells them.

Depending on what you're used to, some aspects may be a problem. It's a 40-pin DIP with 0.6 inches between rows, so it's pretty big. It also needs 5 volts, so 3.3 volt operation is out. Interfacing is easy. It has tri-state outputs. The standard part will work to 125 kHz, using a 2 MHz input clock. The only extra circuit you need is an inverter and some delay. Have the DR output produce an inverted level with a 200 nsec delay at the DRR input, and you're fine. Format - word length, parity, start/stop bit lengths - are all controlled by pin levels. Bit rate is not programmable - you must provide a 5-volt TTL/CMOS oscillator with a frequency 16 times the bit rate.

However, I think you need to rethink your statement that "the output can just be 8 bit with no strobes etc."  How will you detect the arrival of two successive identical words by just looking at the data? Since you have to generate a "data received" pulse anyways (that's what the delay/inverter does), I'd recommend designing something which uses it.

Answer (score 5):

In ancient times, there were stand-alone UART chips that could do this.  I don't know if such parts are still available.

I suspect the easy solution these days is to use a small microcontroller with a UART port and and 8-bit GPIO port - a trivial program can read received data from the UART and output it on the GPIO port.

Comment: The problem with UART chips (which are still plenty around, by the way) is that they need something with a brain in order to configure them. Easiest to start right with a MCU in the first place.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Much to my amazement, I find the Intersel HD3-6402 UART is still available - it is stand-alone - no processor required.  I may have used one about 40 years ago - the number just popped into my head!

Comment: You generally need to configure external UART's though - set baud rate dividers, for example - by which point you may as well have used an MCU anyway.

Comment: The ATtiny2313 has a UART.

Answer (score 0):

I just order a 6402 as this will solve my problem nicely. A bit big, but size isn't too much of an issue.

The reason I can not worry about strobes etc, is that I am actually driving a 4bit data bus which has a complicated 2bits strobe system which I am driving with 2 of the data lines, so a complete write cycles is actually me sending 8 bytes in a row and indirectly doing the strobes that way.

Thanks :)

Comment: I think in this case rather than posting as an answer it sounds like you decided to use the solution posted by WhatRoughBeast so consider accepting his answer to say thanks by pressing the tick button beneath the arrows and pressing the upvote button as well if you like. The reason you decided to go that way could be posted a comment on his answer or as an edit to your question.

Comment: Hi PeterJ, thanks for the tip. I'm pretty new round here! :)